# Ternary operator returns "document.getElementById(...) is not a function" when using const/var/let (javascript)

Tags: javascript, electron, ternary

So, I have this code

```
(async function checkPrinterConnection() {
  (await window.electronAPI.checkPrinterConnection() == undefined) ?
   (document.getElementById('printerIcon').classList.add('printer-icon-error'),
   document.getElementById('printerIcon').title = "Impresora sin conexión",
   document.getElementById('refreshPrinter').innerHTML = 'Reintentar impresora')
   :
   (document.getElementById('printerIcon').classList.remove('printer-icon-error'),
   document.getElementById('printerIcon').title = "Impresora conectada",
   document.getElementById('refreshPrinter').innerHTML = '')
})()
```

that works well, but when I change it to this one below it returns "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is not a function" and I don't understand why

```
const printerIcon = document.getElementById('printerIcon')
const refreshPrinter = document.getElementById('refreshPrinter')
(async function checkPrinterConnection() {
  (await window.electronAPI.checkPrinterConnection() == undefined) ?
   (printerIcon.classList.add('printer-icon-error'),
   printerIcon.title = "Impresora sin conexión",
   refreshPrinter.innerHTML = 'Reintentar impresora')
   :
   (printerIcon.classList.remove('printer-icon-error'),
   printerIcon.title = "Impresora conectada",
   refreshPrinter.innerHTML = '')
})()
```

Comment: The const lines are probably running before the page is rendered.

Comment: what happens if you console.log(document) at first line of second code block?

Comment: Are you purposefully making your code harder to read? If, so they you might consider using a code minifier/uglifier. No need to do it yourself. If not, then don't abuse the conditional operator for this.

Comment: In a browser, `window.document` is never undefined. But maybe Electron is different. You might want to add the appropriate tags.

Comment: I agree with @ivar -- what you are doing here is an if statement.  Coding it this way just obscures your intent and does not make it better in any other way

Comment: So, looks like the problem was a missing ';' at the end of 'document.getElementById('printerIcon')' and document.getElementById('refreshPrinter'), sorry everyone, it was a dumb question

Comment: @fermin You just learned first hand why it is always recommended to use semicolons in JavaScript even when they're not always required.

Comment: @fermin: In fairness, JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion is a dumb feature that exists solely to lull folks into a sense of complacency (it works so often!) just to burn them  with non-obvious errors when they get unlucky. Sadly not so dumb a question.

Comment: @Ivar, I’d say that semicolon auto insert does not trouble most of the times, except when using more complex syntax or abusing, where the coders should already be very much aware of where it fails

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I agree with most of the time, but when you are regularly using IIFE's you'll run into them sooner or later and the errors are not always straight forward. Most linters and code conventions mandate the use of semicolons.